# How to group observations together by type in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset that looks something like this

```
data test;
    input id type $ quantity cost;
    datalines;
    1 one 2 3
    2 one 3 4.5
    3 two 1 5
    4 three 3 12
    5 two 4 20
    6 three 7 28
    7 one 4 6
    8 two 3 15
    ;
run;
```

My goal is to aggregate the quantities and costs of all observations based on type. The end result should look something as follows.

```
data test2;
    input type $ combined_quantity combined_cost;
    datalines;
    one 9 13.5
    two 8 40
    three 10 40
    ;
run;
```

Essentially if rows such as

`id type quantity cost`

`4 three 3 12`

`6 three 7 28`

exist, the result should be

`type combined_quantity combined_cost`

`three 10 40`

as the sum of the 2 rows based on the same type

How do I o this using SAS? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
proc means data=test nway;
  class type;
  var quantity cost;
output out=test2 (drop=_:) sum=combined_quantity combined_cost;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

can be done also using proc sql as shown below.

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select type, 
   sum(quantity) as combined_quantity,
   sum(cost) as combined_cost
from test
group by 1;
```

or in a datastep as

```
  data want(keep = type combined_quantity combined_cost) ;
  set test1;
   by type;
 if first.type then combined_quantity=quantity;
else combined_quantity+quantity;
if first.type then combined_cost=cost;
else combined_cost+cost;
if last.type then output;
run;
```